# Insert after the nth sibling element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, insert, siblings

If I have the following html

```
<div id="example">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

And I want to use jQuery to append the html

```
<div>hello</div>
```

after the third sibling div. Changing the original html to

```
<div id="example">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div>hello</div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

How can I do this based on the class reference

```
$("#example")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) and [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/):

```
$('#example div').eq(2).after('<div>hello</div>');
```

[Fiddle for example.](http://jsfiddle.net/kkpP3/)

Or if you can't change the first selector at all:

```
$('#example').find('div').eq(2).after('<div>hello</div>');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kkpP3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this would be:

```
$($("#example div")[2]).after('<div>Hello</div>');
```

We use the number 2 instead of 3 because of the index of 0, or 3-1; and we re-call jQuery because the first call returns a normal javascript element.

```
$("#example div")[2] // returns 3rd div under element with id 'example' as a js object
$( $("#example")[2] ) // returns 3rd div under element with id 'example' as a jQ object
```